# How to get PowerShell Function to accept multiple parameters for multiple variables

Tags: powershell, csv

I just can't seem to figure out how to make my Function accept multiple parameters correctly.

I have a Function called Get-AdvAppReport. It does a whole lot of data collection and generates a report.  This Function is part of a much larger script.

Inside Function Get-AdvAppReport, I have the following Parameters:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
        Param
        (
            [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME.ToUpper(),
            [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            [string[]]$ServType = ("COM").ToUpper(),
            [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            [string[]]$SiteSize = ("STANDARD").ToUpper(),
            [parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
            [string[]]$User = (Read-Host -prompt "Input User Name:  ")
        )
```

In the main script, I have multiple options, one of which is to generate a report based on the active connection, which has the above variables already defined.  To call it, I'm calling with the following code:

```
Get-AdvAppReport $Computer $ServType $SiteSize
```

It works fine, the report runs and all is well.

What I'm trying to do is have this also work with an Imported CSV file.

At the top of the main script, I have a variable as:

```
$PROD_Serv = Import-CSV ".\Servers_PROD.csv"
```

And to try and call this method, in the script, I am using the following command:

```
Get-AdvAppReport $($PROD_Serv).ComputerName $($PROD_Serv).ServType $($PROD_Serv).SiteSize
```

If there is only one line within the CSV, it all works fine.  On-screen, I have an output showing all is good with the variables.

[image: singleserverworking]

But if there are multiple lines in the CSV, i.e. as the following:

[image: multiCSV]

Then it doesn't work correctly because the second set of parameters is loaded all at once.

For example, the on-screen output shows the following:

[image: multiserverfail]

So it will process the first set of Parameters ($ComputerName) one at a time, but for each of those, it will try to use all of the $ServTypes in the CSV at once.

I've tried so many different ways, and just cannot figure out the logic to make PowerShell accept multiple parameters for multiple variables.  I've been banging my head about this for a few days now, and am stuck.

Anyone have any idea how I can make a function work with multiple parameters and multiple variables?  I just am not understanding why my logic is wrong and have searched high and low, and have not come up with a solution that works for a scenario the same as my current issue.

Edit:
As requested, here is a chunk of the body of the script (sorry, lots of fluff for the report formatting using PS Module PSWriteHTML):

```
    New-HTMLMain -BackgroundColor "#241e69" {
                    
                    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
                    {
                        $Computer = $Computer.ToUpper()
                        
                        Write-Color "`n`nApp Report for ", "$Computer ", "as Type ", "$ServType ", "Initiated...`n`n" -Color Magenta, Cyan, Magenta, Green, Magenta
                        
                        New-HTMLTab -TabName ($Computer + "_" + $ServType) -IconBrands microsoft  {
                            New-HTMLTabOptions -SelectorColor "#707cf1" -SelectorColorTarget "#383392" -Transition -LinearGradient -BorderRadius "10px" -FontSize "15" -FontWeight Bolder -FontFamily "Arial"
                            New-HTMLTableStyle -TextAlign center
                            If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1)
                            {
                                Write-Color "`n     $Computer ", "ONLINE.     `n" -Color Cyan, Green
                                Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer ONLINE"
                                
                                try
                                {
                                    Write-Color "`n     $Computer ", "App Report Data Collection ", "In Progress...     `n" -Color Cyan, White, Green
                                    Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer App Report Data Collection Initiated"
                                    
                                    Get-AdvAppPreReport
                                    
                                    $spacer
                                    $spacer
                                    $spacer
                                    New-HTMLText -Text "End of Report" -Color "#f56e78" -fontsize 20 -Alignment Center -FontWeight Bolder -FontFamily Arial
                            }
                                
                                
                                catch
                                {
                                    Write-Warning "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer Ping Status error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
                                    Write-Color "`n     $Computer ", "Offline.     `n" -Color Cyan, Red
                                    New-HTMLText -Text "$Computer Offline."
                                    Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer Offline."
                                }
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Write-Warning "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer Ping Status error encountered.  -  $($_.Exception.Message)"
                                Write-Color "`n     $Computer ", "OFFLINE.     `n" -Color Cyan, Red
                                
                                Add-Content $LogFile -Value "`n$($Timestamp.Invoke())  -  $Computer Offline."
                                
                                OfflineLog
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And then that Get-AdvAppPreReport Function is basically, If $ServType = DB, then perform these other data collection functions, ElseIF $ServType = WEB, then perform these other function, etc.

Comment: Seems like the issue is in the body of the code, not your parameters. Can you share the body of code, or is too long to post here? `$PROD_Serv.ServType` should suffice as well, you can try passing it explicitly as an array: `,$PROD_Serv.ServType`.

Comment: Can you post the body of your ```Get-AdvAppReport``` function? It it's big, try to reduce it to just the minimum that outputs your problematic logging messages. My guess is you're doing something like ```foreach( $computer in $ComputerName ) { write-host "App Report for $Computer as Type $ServType Initiated..." }``` where you're iterating over the items in the ```$ComputerName```parameter and expecting ```$ServType``` to contain just the matching value from the "parallel  array" parameters, but it actually contains the entire array. This would work for a single item, but not multiple items...

Comment: I'll edit the post so I can format it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comments, you're passing three [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) into your function, equivalent to:

```
Get-AdvAppReport `
    -ComputerName @( "SERV01",   "SQL01", "MGMT01" ) `
    -ServType     @( "NTIER",    "DB",    "COM" ) `
    -SiteSize     @( "STANDARD", "LARGE", "STANDARD" )
```

You're then iterating over the `$ComputerName` array with something similar to:

```
foreach( $computer in $ComputerName )
{
    write-host "App Report for $computer as Type $ServType Initiated..."
}
```

and getting the output:

```
App Report for SERV01 as Type NTIER DB COM Initiated...
App Report for SQL01 as Type NTIER DB COM Initiated...
App Report for MGMT01 as Type NTIER DB COM Initiated...
```

The problem is that inside your `foreach` loop, you're expecting `$ServType` to contain just the item in the matching position in the second parameter, which isn't how a `foreach` loop works.

What you need to do instead is something like:

```
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $ComputerName.Length; $i++ )
{
    write-host "App Report for $($ComputerName[$i]) as Type $($ServType[$i]) Initiated..."
}
```

and then your output will be:

```
App Report for SERV01 as Type NTIER Initiated...
App Report for SQL01 as Type DB Initiated...
App Report for MGMT01 as Type COM Initiated...
```

**However** you've now got potential issues if the parallel arrays aren't actually parallel - e.g. one of them is `$null` or a different length, so you might want to consider passing in an array of "report rows" instead:

```
function Get-AdvAppReport {
    param( [object[]] $ReportRows )
    foreach( $row in $ReportRows )
    {
        write-host "App Report for $($row.ComputerName) as Type $($row.ServType) Initiated..."
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply pass your converted csv object in:

```
$PROD_Serv = Import-CSV ".\Servers_PROD.csv"

Get-AdvAppReport -ReportRows $PROD_Serv
```

---

As an aside, your original code works when there's only one row because you're doing this:

```
Get-AdvAppReport `
    -ComputerName @( "SERV01" ) `
    -ServType     @( "NTIER" ) `
    -SiteSize     @( "STANDARD" )
```

and the entire `$ServType` array is just a single item so it *appears* to be working correctly when your original `foreach` loop runs, but logically it still suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Okay, I see what you have going on here, and when I just plug it into my script, it does work the way I ultimately want it to.  I'm going to have to do some tweaking, i.e. thinking if I can just add your example of ReportsRow param but also keeping my other ones so I can make it more versatile within my big script (and also maintain this is a separate stand-alone script, but am lazily incorporating into my main tool as a function).  You've definitely got me on the right track now though, so very much appreciated!

Comment: You could use ParameterSets (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameter_sets?view=powershell-7.2) to accept the old "parallel arrays" approach, and add a new ```-ReportRows``` parameter set for future use. If a call uses the "parallel arrays" parameter set your function can convert them into an array of report rows before running the report generation code.

Comment: Anytime I try to use ParameterSets then the attempt to call Get-AdvAppReport -ReportRows $Servers_Prod fails with an error that parameters can't be resolved, even if I have Mandatory set to $false.  I was trying to work around all this by not using ParameterSets, but instead just using If/Else with $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ReportRows').  Going to try to play with it more and see if I can make it work.  I know I could just create two functions if I can't figure it out, but just seems crazy redundant since it alone is 10k+ lines of code.

Comment: If you can’t get parameter sets working you could possibly (i) post another question (ii) write a small wrapper / shim that takes the parallel array parameters, converts them into report rows and then calls the other version of the function and returns the result - that will avoid duplicating the body of the main function

Comment: seems very rudimentary, but it seems to be working with an If/Else statement where ($ReportRows -ne $null ), then use foreach ($Row in $ReportRows), Else {foreach $Computer in $ComputerName}.  I feel like this isn't the proper way to do it, but thus far is working in every scenario I've tested it with.  Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this it's stupid but it might work.

Try puting in another For Loop like

```
$a=Import-CSV -Path "<.\path to your file>"

ForEach ($i in $a)
{

Get-AdvAppReport $($i).ComputerName $($i).ServType $($i).SiteSize

}
```

This is  just something i thought off of top of my head. Might not work but keep me posted. You can moderate it and filter through it with IF just use $i.ServType or any of those cause $i will be one of the lines that is in queue in For Loop.

Comment: That will generate 3 reports with one row in each (see the call to ```New-HTMLMain``` before the ```foreach``` loop, which would be called 3 times) . It looks like the OP wants one report (i.e. one call to ```Get-AdvAppReport```) with all three rows included in it...

Comment: Yes, what it does is that New-HTMLTab section creates a tab for each server within a single report.  PSWriteHTML is pretty amazing at creating nice reports once you figure out all the options.

Comment: Ok this is from cmd. New to powershell but i use it to draw reports from azuread. And we use export at the end of function like >> report file and that puts everything line after line. Can that work in this case since report is in HTML